# PCIe extension card for NVMe SSD isn't recognized

Tags: drivers, 20.04, ssd, nvme, pcie

I've bought the ICY BOX PCIe extension card for M.2 NVMe SSD (IB-PCI214M2-HSL), and an AORUS NVME Gen4 SSD on it, but my system doesn't recognize it...

When I do this command:

```
sudo lsblk -f
```

My disk isn't listed!

I try this:

```
sudo lspci -v
```

And the result is:

```
0c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation E16 PCIe4 NVMe Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Phison Electronics Corporation E16 PCIe4 NVMe Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 78, NUMA node 0
    Memory at fce00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [80] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=9 Masked-
    Capabilities: [e0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [f8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [110] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
    Capabilities: [1e0] Data Link Feature <?>
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [340] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [378] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

0d:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [400] Data Link Feature <?>
    Capabilities: [410] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [440] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
```

My motherboard is the X570 AORUS MASTER, and the extension card is plugged in to the second PCIe port, running on Ubuntu server 20.04.2.

Thanks in advance for helping me :)

Answer (score 2):

Just updating BIOS Firmware made everything work fine!